# Selecting an <option> from a <select> with JavaScript in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html-select, addeventlistener, domcontentloaded

I'm trying to have JavaScript listen for the event that an option is chosen. And once JavaScript knows I've clicked one of those options, it's supposed update how the submit button functions. It is very similar to just an old fashioned onclick="" inline with each option, but in a safer setting(which also doesn't seem to work in Chrome). So this is my small bit of code, and it works in Firefox, IE, **but not Chrome.**

**HTML:**

```
                <select>
                    <option id="zero">--</option>
                    <option id="one">Choice one</option>
                    <option id="two">Choice Two</option>
                    <option id="three">Choice Three</option>
                  </select>

                  <button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
        function _(el)
{
    return document.getElementById(el);
}
function resetOption()
{
    _('submit').setAttribute('onclick', '');
    _('submit').value = "Choose location";

}
function optionOneChosen()
{
    _('submit').setAttribute('onclick', 'functionOne()');
    _('submit').value = "Location one";
}
function optionTwoChosen() 
{
    _('submit').setAttribute('onclick', 'functionTwo()');
    _('submit').value = "Location two";   
}
function optionThreeChosen() 
{
    _('submit').setAttribute('onclick', 'functionThree()');
    _('submit').value = "Location three";   
}

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function ()
{

    _('zero').addEventListener('click', resetOption);
    _('one').addEventListener('click', optionOneChosen);
    _('two').addEventListener('click', optionTwoChosen);
    _('three').addEventListener('click', optionThreeChosen);
});
```

I tried to do some debugging, and it seems like the system breaks inside the 'DOMContentLoaded' function, as if Chrome doesn't recognize the property I'm trying to access. So what am I missing? Or for that matter, is Chrome implementing security features that the other browsers haven't standardized yet?
Thanks a ton!
Jeffrey

Answer (score 0):

This will yield the same result:

```
var select = document.querySelector("select"),
    button = document.querySelector("button");

select.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    var option = this.options[this.selectedIndex];

    switch (option.id) {
        case "zero": button.value = "Choose Location"; break;
        case "one": button.value = "Location one"; break;
        case "two": button.value = "Location two"; break;
        case "three": button.value = "Location three"; break;
    }
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hkoh9gm7/)